# copy specific characters from a string to another string

Tags: c

lets say i have 2 strings

```
char str_cp[50],str[50];
str[]="how are you"
```

and i want to put the second word ex "are" into another string named str_cp so if i use

```
printf("%s ,%s",str,str_cp);
```

will be like

```
how are you 
are
```

how can i do that?
(i tried strncpy function but it can copy only specific characters from beggining of the string )
is there any way to use a pointer which points at the 4th character of the string and use it in the strncpy function to copy the first 3 characters but the beggining point to be the 4th character ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> I tried strncpy function but it can copy only specific characters from beggining of the string

`strcpy` family of functions will copy from the point that you tell it to copy. For example, to copy from the fifth character on, you can use

```
strncpy(dest, &src[5], 3);
```

or

```
strncpy(dest, src+5, 3); // Same as above, using pointer arithmetic
```

Note that `strncpy` will *not* null-terminate the string for you, unless you hit the end of the source string:

> No null-character is implicitly appended at the end of destination if source is longer than num (thus, in this case, destination may not be a null terminated C string).

You need to null-terminate the result yourself:

```
strncpy(dest, &src[5], 3);
dest[3] = '\0';
```

Comment: thank you.I thought that strncopy can start only from the start point of the string

Comment: @user1809300 C string functions have no idea where the string actually begins: to them, a string is just a pointer into the memory. They think it begins wherever you tell them that it does, so you can freely pass them a pointer into the middle of the string if that is what you need.

Comment: i have another question: if i save in str_cp the word "are" and i use another time the strncpy to copy from str the last 3 chars ex "you" in the str_cp then in str_cp the "are" will be removed and it will have only the new word "you" ? or i need to free this part of memory and then copy to str_cp

Comment: @user1809300 Yes, `strcpy` will overwrite whatever is there. Of course you can also play the same trick on `dest`, and pass `dest+3` or `&dest[3]` as the destination to "paste" the copy of the second string *after* the first one. If `dest` contains a null-terminated string, you can also use `strcat` to perform concatenation.