# Slicing in C compared with Python

Tags: python, c, pointers, slice, memory-address

I have been trying to figure out a substring method like Python's splice, e.g. 'hello'[2:4].

**OLD**: The pointers `new` and `toret` (to return) are the same, but when stored in `hello`, it has a new address. Is there a way to maintain the address and get the slice printed out?

**NEW**: What is the best way to put chars in the buffer?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//char * substr(char *str, int start, int end);
//void substr(char *str, int start, int end);
void get_substr(char *str, int start, int end, char *buffer);

int main() {
    char word[] = "Clayton";
    char buffer[15];
    printf("buffer is now %s",get_substr(word,2,5,buffer);
    return 0;
}


void get_substr(char *str, int start, int end, char *buffer) {
    int length = end - start;
    printf("length %d\n",length);
    //char buffer[length]; //init normal array    
    //assign values from *str
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        buffer[i] = *(str+i+start);
    }
}


//char * substr(char *str, int start, int end) {
/* char * substr(char *str, int start, int end) {
    int length = end - start;
    printf("length %d\n",length);
    char buffer[length]; //init normal array    
    //assign values from *str
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        buffer[i] = *(str+i+start);
        printf("i=%d buffer[i]=%c ptr=%c\n",i,buffer[i],*(str+i+start));
    }
    //add endline if not present
    if (buffer[length] != '\0') {
        buffer[length] = '\0';
        printf("buffer[%d] is %c\n",length,buffer[length]);
        printf("0 added\n");
    }
    printf("buffer %s %p\n",buffer,buffer);
    printf("len(buffer) is %d\n",strlen(buffer));
    char *toret;
    toret = (char*) &buffer;
    printf("toret %s %p\n",toret,toret);
    return toret;
} */
```

Sorry this may be a duplicate, but I can't find the same examples on this domain. **I AM NEW TO C!**

Comment: Don't take it bad but your code is so littered with obvious bugs that answering your question is downright impossible. Using `new` as a variable name? Returning the address of a stack-allocated variable? Accessing index *n* of a 0-indexed array of length *n*? Confusing `sizeof` with the length of a string?

Comment: @spectras: while using `new` as a variable name is not encouraged in C (I don't encourage it, for example — or the use of any other C++ keyword that is not a C keyword), nevertheless, the question is tagged C, and not C++, and a C compiler _must_ accept `new` as a valid variable name.  If it doesn't, it isn't a C compiler but is probably a C++ compiler in disguise.  (This is not a claim that the code is good — it isn't!  It is just an observation that `new` is a valid name for general use in C code.)

Comment: @spectras Thanks, after reviewing some [strncpy](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14042078/5645103)s my code seems to work now

Comment: Well, in addition to the bad idea of using `new` as a variable name, there were a number of actual bugs, and it seems you fixed all of them so, great job!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't return a pointer to a buffer that is declared locally within the function.  That memory resides on the stack, and the next function call will likely overwrite that memory.  You would need to use `malloc` to create the memory you need if you are going to return it to the calling function, which then needs to be cleaned up with `free`, once you are done with it.

That being said, it's usually not wise to allocate the memory in the called function and return it.  In order to prevent the caller from forgetting to clean up the memory, I would recommend requesting a buffer into which the substring will be copied.

I would change the function signature to return a void, and take an additional buffer into which the substring will be copied:

```
void get_substr(char *str, int start, int end, char *buffer)
```

Then, in your calling function, you can do this:

```
int main() {
    char name[] = "Clayton";
    char buffer[10];

    get_substr(name, 0, 3, buffer);
    /* "Cla" now copied into buffer */

    printf("%s", buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, since this is a substring function, and you know that the string is completely contained within the original string, you could return the size of the string's length and a pointer to the start of the string (within the original string).

Your signature could look like this:

```
int substr(char *str, int start, int end, char *substr)
```

And usage could look like this:

```
int main() {
    char name[] = "Clayton";
    char *substr;
    int substr_len = substr(name, 0, 3, substr);
    /* substr now points to name, substr_len = 3 */

    /* Copy substring to buffer to print */
    char buffer[10];
    strncpy(buffer, substr, substr_len);

    printf("%s", buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, is my code almost the same for the former?

Comment: @ClaytonWahlstrom I don't know that your code is implemented correctly.  I would first validate `start >= 0` and `start <= end`, and use `strlen` to validate the `end` parameter (to make sure it's not past the end of the string).  If you go with the first approach, you should use `strncpy` to copy the characters to the buffer.  If you go with the second approach, you can calculate the `substr_len` and set the `substr` pointer to `str + start`.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but something similar as follows should work:

```
char name[] = "Clayton";
int slice_begin = 0, slice_end = 3;
printf("%.*s", slice_end - slice_begin, name + slice_begin);
```

**Update** Based on this technique, you can use two variables to represent a substring: a pointer to the beginning of the slice, and an integer representing the length.

Comment: How does it work in a function? (or does it need to be?)

Comment: @ClaytonWahlstrom It all depends your need. I consider this too simple to be a function myself, but if you want it to be more object oriented, you can definitely wrap everything in a struct (pointer and the length), and create a function to manage the struct.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to emulate Python's slice, I'd go with something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

char *slice(char *string, int start, int stop, int step) {
    size_t string_length = ceil(fabs((stop - start) / (float) step));

    char *new_string = malloc(string_length + 1);

    for (int i = start, j = 0; j < string_length; i += step, j++) {
        new_string[j] = string[i];
    }

    new_string[string_length] = '\0';

    return new_string;
}

int main() {
    char *name = "Clayton";

    char *hello = slice(name, 0, 3, 1);

    printf("%s\n", hello);

    free(hello);

    char *letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    char *goodbye = slice(letters, strlen(letters) - 1, -1, -1);

    printf("%s\n", goodbye);

    free(goodbye);

    return 0;
}
```

With output:

```
Cla
zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba
```